# Change layout of listview item onclick

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a `ListView` with custom adaptor that I molded off the example shown [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters).

I want to take the user's selection and inflate a different layout for that selection. So that I can expand the view to display more information when an item is selected. Can I simply inflate a new layout onclick using something like this?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout, null);
```

After this section of code I would populate the individual `TextView` and `ImageView` objects, just as I did in the initial list only this time I would include more fields. Is this right or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this won't work since you haven't done anything to the view that you got . you only replaced its reference (and didn't do anything with the newly inflated view) and not really modified anything in the "views tree" .

what you can do is to empty the view from its content and add new content into it .

don't forget that in the getView you will have to do the same thing and return a view with this content.

Comment: So I need to clear entire listview? or can I clear that one item and replace only that section? I think this is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: no , i didn't say to clear the listview , i said to clear the view that you get in the onListItemClick , which is the view of the row that was clicked . listview contains all of the items and you should not mess with its children in any way . i suggest you to watch "the world of listView" for a lot of tips of listView : http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: yes , it's very recommended to watch google io videos . they also have a nice tutorial about handling bitmaps efficiently , in case you use them (usually them come together with listview when handling things from the web ) : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html